# not resolve local domins from /etc/hosts

Tags: macos, dns, router

Somehow I have a problem (previously everything was ok), hosts form /etc/hosts can't bre resolved.

I have local domain in /etc/hosts, like

```
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

It's loading in browser well but too long, from firebug i see that biggest part of time spending for DNS lookup.

I tried `nslookup test.local`

I see

```
$ nslookup test.local
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

but ping `test.local` working well :)

my DNS settings are next:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I did not modified that file manually, it just represent GUI settings situation.

```
    $ scutil --dns
    DNS configuration

    resolver #1
    nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
    reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
```

Everything become solved if I turn OFF mac os included firewall.
How I can make local pages opening faster and keep firewall turning ON ?

Comment: We are experiencing this issues since Sierra (we = several machines). Everytime we enter a certain network with assigned DNS via router hosts file is ignored. Simple solution: Switch DNS provider on router. But this is necessary every morning :-( WTF? After this it resolves again against local hosts file.